# Can't save the config file turtlebot_node.py because I don't own the file

Tags: permissions

I have installed turtlebot on my robot and also on the desktop. I am using the software on a 4XXX roomba. The baud rate is the same as the turtlebot. But, the port is not the same. I have tried and tried to edit the turtlebot_node.py configuration file and it will not let me save it. It says I don't have permissions.

When I try to change the permissions, it tells me that I am not the owner so i cannot change the permission. This happens on both the netbook AND the desktop. I am loss to what to do next. chmod and chown do not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried  sudo -s at terminal before proceeding with chmod? If not, type at terminal `sudo -s` press ENTER input your system password and change to the file directory, at terminal type ***cd /type folder location here/ type filename here***, next  `sudo chgrp type filename here` press ENTER and `sudo chmod g+rwx type filename` press ENTER. I hope that would help out with the situation a bit. Thank you.